# Github Actions - Retrieving Dependencies from Cache

Tags: python, github, dependencies, github-actions

I have set up a Github Action to launch a python project in my own repo.

The project needs external libraries and it executes efficiently if, in every run, I install them.

I tried however to cache them after the installation and to retrieve them from the cache in every run but this is not working; in every run, the cache is hit but the dependencies are still getting installed.

Am I missing a step?

```
name: Daily Python Script

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 19 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch: #Manual trigger
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    permissions:
        # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
        # added or changed files to the repository.
        contents: write

    steps:
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: 3.9

      - name: Update Node.js to v16
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16

      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Restore Cached Dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.cache/pip
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pip-${{ hashFiles('requirements.txt') }}
                    
      - name: Debug Cache
        run: |
            echo "Cache hit: ${{ steps.cache-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit }}"
            ls -l ~/.cache/pip

      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      - name: Run Python Script
        run: python main_v1.py

      - name: Commit and Push Logs
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: Automated Change
          repository: .
          commit_user_name: My GitHub Actions Bot # defaults to "github-actions[bot]"
          commit_user_email: my-github-actions-bot@example.org # defaults to "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          commit_author: Author <actions@github.com> # defaults to author of the commit that triggered the run
```

The *requirement.txt* file includes the following:

```
numpy==1.21.6
oauth2client==4.1.3
pandas==1.5.3
pytz==2022.7.1
Requests==2.31.0
selenium==4.9.0
trycourier==4.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

My original approach was not up do date and the reason for the `ModuleNotFoundError` is that **setup-python** caches and retrieves dependencies under the hood since Nov 23rd, 2021.
(https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-23-github-actions-setup-python-now-supports-dependency-caching/)

More information can be found here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

Here is the updated yml file:

```
name: Daily Python Script

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 19 * * *"
  workflow_dispatch: #Manual trigger

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

permissions:
    # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
    # added or changed files to the repository.
    contents: write

steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Set up Python
    uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version: '3.9'
      cache: 'pip' # caching pip dependencies

  - name: Install Dependencies
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install -r requirements.txt
    
  - name: Run Python Script
    run: python main_v1.py

  - name: Commit and Push Logs
    uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
    with:
      commit_message: Automated Change
      repository: .
      commit_user_name: My GitHub Actions Bot # defaults to "github-actions[bot]"
      commit_user_email: my-github-actions-bot@example.org # defaults to "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
      commit_author: Author <actions@github.com> # defaults to author of the commit that triggered the run
```

In the **build log**, if the cache is hit and the `requirements.txt` has not changed, when the *Install Dependencies* is reached, the Action will show the dependencies being retrieved from the cache:

```
Collecting numpy==1.21.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached numpy-1.21.6-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
```

User is happy again!

Answer (score 0):

- Step "*Restore Cached Dependencies*" does not have `id` set [to `cache-dependencies`]
- Without `id`, there's no way to get output values from that step
- `${{ steps.cache-dependencies.outputs.cache-hit }}` will always return empty string
- Step "*Install Dependencies*" condition becomes `if: "" != "true"` and evaluates to `true`
- Dependencies are installed over and over again making user sad

Comment: Thank you very much, @Samira.
This was the reason why despite a cache hit, the dependencies would still be installed.

`id` added, the install skipped but now I'm facing another problem; I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'` error, as if the cache is hit, but the dependency are not loaded.

I tried again, deleted existing cache and added the "google-api-python-client" module which was installed separately.

The first run, smooth. The second, cache is hit but `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'` error is returned.

Any advice?

Comment: Thank you.
Due to the behaviour setup-python@v4, the dependencies were actually being retrieved from the cache, without needing of the if clause (needed I think until v2).

What I would not expect was to see actions in the _Install Dependencies_ section, but after a more careful reading, I could see it stated `using cached [modulename]`.

Thank you again for your help!